# Update large amount of rows from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have Table1 (Id, Row1, Row2) and Table2 (Id, Row1, Row2) with same schema.

In table1 I have data with the same id than in table2 and I want to update Row1 and Row2 for each corresponding Id. But I have a lot of data (around 10 000 000 rows) and it's very slow with a loop.

Is it possible to update all rows faster?

Note: I can't truncate and bulk insert because in table2 I can have data that is not in table1.

Comment: Use a `JOIN`. SQL is a set based language, it excels at set based methods and is awful at iterative ones. If you are using a loop you are almost always doing it wrong; I can count the number of times you should be using a loop in SQL with my fingers.

Comment: Why don't you add what you are currently doing to your question, that way no one is going to waste time suggesting anything you might already be doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  Just join the two tables together, and run an UPDATE over the results of the JOIN,  eg:

```
with q as
(
   select t1.id, t1.Col1, t1.Col2, t1.Col3,
                 t2.Col1 Col1_new, t2.Col2 Col2_new t2.Col3 Col3_new
   from Table1 t1
   join Table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
)
--select * from q
update q set Col1 = Col1_new, Col2 = Col2_new, Col3 = Col3_new
```

Comment: Great, look likes very nice ; never thought of that this way